# Is there some relationship for all points on a rectangle?

Tags: geometry, 3d

For a line in 3D space, you can know that for each P on the line with endpoints A and B and length L, it holds that ||P-A|| + ||P-B|| = L

My question is: is there a similar expression for points on an arbitrary rectangle in 3D space? You can't add up the distances to the corners, I checked that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rectangle $R$ (or convex quadrilateral) has corners $A,B,C,D$,
then any point $p$ inside $R$ satisfies 
$$
p = \alpha A + \beta B + \gamma C + \delta D
$$
where $\alpha , \beta , \gamma , \delta \in [0,1]$ and
$$
\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta = 1
$$
See Wikipedia's article on [*convex combination*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination).